# Help understanding proof of $\text{Tr}_{M/K}(\alpha) = \text{Tr}_{L/K}(\text{Tr}_{M/L}(\alpha)), \, \forall \alpha \in M$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I'm trying to understand [this](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BIE) proof (lemma 9.20.5, which is based on lemma 9.20.4). But I don't understand the proof of lemma 9.20.4. It involves $\text{Tr}_K(\varphi : V \to V)$. The definition for $\text{Tr}_K$ is given initially, but I don't understand how it works for linear transformations on $L$-vector spaces. If we have such a transformation, won't a matrix associated with it have entries in $L$? If so, what is the meaning of $\text{Tr}_K$ of a matrix with entries which are not in $K$?

I thought of it reducing this matrix mod K, but if we have the base $l_1 = 1_K, \dots, l_m$ ($m \geq 2$) of $L/K$, the base $v_1, \dots, v_n$ ($n \geq 2$) of $V$ and the linear transformation $\varphi(a_1 v_1 + \dots + a_n v_n) = (a_1 + a_1)v_1 + a_2 v_2, \forall a_i \in L$ for example, what should $\text{Tr}_K(\varphi : V \to V)$ evaluate to? If I'm not mistaken, the RHS evaluates to $\text{Tr}_{L/K}(\text{Tr}_L(\varphi : V \to V)) = \text{Tr}_{L/K}((a_1+a_1)+a_2) = (1_K + 1_K)\text{Tr}_{L/K}(a_1) + \text{Tr}_{L/K}(a_2)$ and to finish we just get the matrices with entries in $K$ of the transformations $x \to a_1 x$ and $x \to a_2 x$. This doesn't seem to be euqal to LHS with this interpretation of reducing mod K, so it is probably wrong. So what's the correct meaning for $\text{Tr}_K(\varphi : V \to V)$?

Comment: You are never asked to take the trace over $K$ of a matrix with entries not in $K$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have fields $K\leq L\leq M$.

Any $L$-linear tranformation is also a $K$-linear transformation (by restriction of scalars). Multiplication by $\alpha\in M$ is an $L$-linear transformation: for all $x,y\in M$ and $r\in L$,
$$\begin{align*}
\alpha(x+y) &= \alpha x + \alpha y\\
\alpha(rx) &= r(\alpha x).
\end{align*}$$
In particular, this is also $K$-linear.

So you have this map $\varphi\colon M\to M$. If you view it as a $K$-linear transformation, then you can calculate $\mathrm{Tr}_{M/K}(\alpha)$, which will be an element of $K$.

Or you can view it as an $L$-linear transformation, and calculation $\mathrm{Tr}_{M/L}(\alpha)$. This will give you an element $\beta\in L$. Now you have $\beta\colon L\to L$, multiplication by $\beta$ in $L$. This is a $K$-linear transformation, so you can compute $\mathrm{Tr}_{L/K}(\beta)$. This will be an element of $K$.

The equality in question says that $\mathrm{Tr}_{L/K}(\beta) = \mathrm{Tr}_{M/K}(\alpha)$. That is, that
$$\mathrm{Tr}_{M/K}(\alpha) = \mathrm{Tr}_{L/K}(\mathrm{Tr}_{M/L}(\alpha)).$$
At *no point* are you taking $\mathrm{Tr}_K$ of a matrix with entries in $L$.

Here's an example: consider $K=\mathbb{Q}$, $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, $M=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$. Let $B_1=[1,\sqrt{2}]$ be a basis for $L$ over $K$; let $B_2=[1,\sqrt{3}]$ be a basis for $M$ over $L$. And let $B_3=[1,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{6}]$ be a basis for $M$ over $K$. Let $\alpha=1+\sqrt{6}$.

To compute $\mathrm{Tr}_{M/K}(\alpha)$, we consider the linear transformation "multiplication by $\alpha$ on $M$", relative to basis $B_3$. The effect is:
$$\begin{align*}
1 &\longmapsto 1+\sqrt{6}\\
\sqrt{2}&\longmapsto \sqrt{2}+\sqrt{12} = \sqrt{2}+2\sqrt{3}\\
\sqrt{3}&\longmapsto \sqrt{3}+\sqrt{18}=3\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}\\
\sqrt{6} &\longmapsto \sqrt{6}+6.
\end{align*}$$
The corresponding matrix is
$$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 6\\
0 & 1 & 3 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right).$$
So $\mathrm{Tr}_{M/L}(1+\sqrt{6}) = 4$.

Now consider this as a transformation over $L$; relative to basis $B_2$, we have:
$$\begin{align*}
1 &\mapsto 1+\sqrt{6} = 1 +\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3}\\
\sqrt{3}&\mapsto 3\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}
\end{align*}$$
The corresponding matrix with entries in $L$ is
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 3\sqrt{2}\\
\sqrt{2} & 1
\end{array}\right).$$
So $\mathrm{Tr}_{M/L}(1+\sqrt{6}) = 2$.
Now we consider "multiplication by $2$" as a $K$-linear transformation $L\to L$. Relative to basis $B_1$, we have:
$$\begin{align*}
1 &\mapsto 2\\
\sqrt{2} & \mapsto 2\sqrt{2}
\end{align*}$$
so the corresponding matrix is
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
2 & 0\\
0 & 2
\end{array}\right).$$
Thus, $\mathrm{Tr}_{L/K}(2) = 4$.

Hence, we have
$$\mathrm{Tr}_{L/K}(\mathrm{Tr}_{M/L}(1+\sqrt{6})) = \mathrm{Tr}_{L/K}(2) = 4 = \mathrm{Tr}_{M/K}(1+\sqrt{6}),$$
as expected.

Comment: Thanks! Now that this is clear, I have another question: the proof mentions selecting $\varphi$ such that there's exactly one entry in the matrix which is one and the others are all zero (I assume he's talking $\varphi$ as a linear transformation on $L$-vector spaces).

It is clear to me that if we fix any base $v_1, \dots, v_n$ of $V$, one can define $\varphi$ in any way we want so there certainly will be such a matrix. However, suppose we fix a basis $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n$ of $M/L$. Why is there an $\alpha \in M$ such that $x \to \alpha x$ works?

Comment: Additionally, if there were such an $\alpha$ and we take one of the columns which has every element equal to zero, wouldn't that mean that $\alpha \alpha_i = 0$, which can't happen?

Comment: @ArthurQueirozMoura: No column has all entries equal to $0$, unless $\alpha=0$ (in which case the entire matrix is the zero matrix). The proof does not claim such a thing happens: it claims you can find a basis with the property that there will be a column which has first entry equal to $1$ and all other entries *in that column* equal to $0$, etc. He does not say "one entry equal to $1$ and all other entries in the matrix* equal to zero", it's all other entries **in that column** equal to $0$.

Comment: I'm having a hard time seeing how this helps making a direct computation of the traces. Could you please summarize how it is done?

Comment: @ArthurQueirozMoura It doesn't. That part of the proof is for computation of norms, not traces.

Comment: It says on the first paragraph: "Choose an isomorphism $V=L^{\oplus n}$ so that $\varphi$ corresponds to an $n \times n$ matrix. In the case of traces, both sides of the formula are additive in $\varphi$. Hence we can assume that $\varphi$ corresponds to the matrix with exactly one nonzero entry in the $(i, j)$ spot. In this case a direct computation shows both sides are equal."
Isn't he talking about the trace here? I didn't understand what he did. Could you please explain it to me?

Comment: @ArthurQueirozMoura I was looking at a different place in the page. Which is why (1) Questions here should be **self-contained**, and not rely on material that needs to be checked elsewhere. And (2) Questions should be **focused**. I've answered the question you actually asked, now you are using the comment section to ask a **different** question. That is not the purpose of comments.

Comment: Ok, I will create a new question